# Pinguy Builder Issue

Tags: lubuntu, ubiquity

I have tried to build a Linux distro based on Lubuntu 17.10, and the ISO generates fine and everything, but when I boot it up and install it, it fails during install and when I go to try again, it says that "ubi-partman" ended with error code 10 and when trying again it just won't work on there. Please help me as I want to make my distro as user-friendly as possible.

Seriously, I actually kinda need an answer here. The distro in question is Pixel OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix for 17.04/17.10/18.04 Install failures after remaster with PinguyBuilder

Problem definition:

Ever since 17.04 remastersys/PinguyBuilder/Forks fail to compete
the install process.

This is due to the change from Swap Partition to Swap File in 17.04.

The problem occurs because we are including the the swapfile created
by the initial install of Ubuntu/Flavors in the remaster which causes
errors in /lib/partman/finish.d/25create_swapfile and therefor the
install fails.

The fix:

The fix is to add "/swapfile" to the list of excluded files in the settings
dialog of PinguyBuilder under "Files to exclude".

In other words change "/windows /dos" to "/windows /dos /swapfile"

I have tested this in 18.04 on both a mini generated Unity respin(GTK)
as well as my 18.04 Plasma(e.g. KDE) respin. I also verified that the
newly created swapfile was present in the newly installed system and
showed up in "ls -lh /", cat /proc/swaps and the /etc/fstab file
(e.g. that is was correctly created and enabled).

Hope this helps,
WolfLand